# KLM refused luggage return during 3 day delay

Tags: luggage, klm

I was due to fly out from Amsterdam to Nice yesterday, but the flight was cancelled by KLM. The soonest available flight they will give me is in 3 days time. I accepted that as I have no real other option. However, they are refusing to return my luggage to me during this time, stating that it will simply be loaded onto the flight in 3 days. Is this legal? I only have very light hand luggage, and everything I need is in my ch clef luggage which they refuse to return. I would like to know if this is normal procedure and if there is anything I can do so that they give me my luggage during the delay so I don’t have to go out and replace all my essential items that I will need for 3 days (clothes, make up, toiletries etc).
Thanks for any insights you might have.

Comment: Try contacting them through Twitter and Facebook. Companies tend to be more accomodating when contacted through social media.

Comment: It's been ~2 days already. Getting your luggage now may be too late. But check this site out. I have no idea if it's legit, so I would not use its service if I were you. But you can probably verify its underlying claims by googling around. https://www.claimflights.co.uk/airlines/klm-royal-dutch Hopefully you documented everything, as you may need to prove that they didn't want to return that luggage to you. There is zero reason for that, not even a weather delay would be a legitimate excuse.

Answer (score 4):

It is understandable that it is diffcult for them to sort the luggage out and give it to you, but according to the usual rules, they should be responsible for paying for your necessities, as well as the hotels and food, as the delay is their fault. It should be cheaper for them to get your luggage out than to pay for you buying new items, but they may have the choice in that (meaning they probably can choose to give you money instead).

Either way, they are responsible for your cost during the forced stay, and they are legally required to inform you about it. Contact them to get what they owe you, and file a complaint if they don’t want to.

Worst case you can buy some new wardrobe on their nickel, and have some paid vacation in the three days.

Comment: So, I realize this answer is over 3 years old, however, according to _what_ rules? You don't specify them, or even better, link to them. As it stands, it's according to the rules of Aganju....